# Conditional/Check: IF author has no First Name THEN

Tags: author, conditional-content

I'm looking to find a way to check if the author has included their first name (at registration) and if they haven't then do something... I have no idea where to start, or finish, but I assume it looks a little like this???

```
<?php if (get_the_author_meta('first_name', true)) { ?>
// do something
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter for `get_the_author_meta` is the user iD.

If you're using the function within the loop, the user ID would be the ID of the current user if not you would have to specify the user ID.

```
if ( !get_the_author_meta('first_name', $user_id )) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: How would I apply that same check to the current logged in author?

Comment: To apply this to the current user,your `$user_id = get_current_user_id()`